# Trouble installing OpenCV with Homebrew

Tags: macos, opencv, gcc, makefile, homebrew

I can't seem to get opencv installed with homebrew on OS X Yosemite. I have the latest version of xcode installed along with the command line tools.

Here's the error I'm getting.

```
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.0.0'
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error, also on OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a problem with Homebrew and Xcode linking to the correct version of GCC. You can try installing the updated [Xcode command line tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html) after you upgrade to Yosemite and Xcode 6.1+.

Try running

```
xcode-select --install
```

to download and install the most current command line tools, or do so within Xcode.

You can also try reinstalling GCC 4.2 from within Homebrew:

```
brew tap homebrew/versions && brew install apple-gcc42
brew link --force apple-gcc42
ln -nsf $(which gcc-4.2) /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
```

Besides that, it may be a problem with Homebrew directly, and you might consider installing OpenCV manually.

Comment: I have the most current command line tools installed. I think the problem is that homebrew is using gcc-4.2. When I enter gcc-4.2 into my shell it says `couldn't understand kern.osversion '14.0.0'`

Comment: Yeah this seems to be an active issue with Homebrew. Consider installing manually?

Comment: I've been having trouble with the manual installation also. Is there any way I can specify a different version of gcc for homebrew to use?

Comment: Does `brew doctor` tell you anything useful?

Comment: Nothing particularly useful

Comment: Hm not sure about the specifics of Homebrew and GCC, so I can just recommend checking out cmake to install on your Mac